# Batch command line argument matching

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I really can't understand why this refuses to work.

```
@ECHO OFF


    SET CURRDIR=%CD%


    if [%1%]==[1] GOTO ONE 
    if [%1%]==[2] GOTO TWO 
    if [%1%]==[3] GOTO THREE


    :ONE
    call "%CURRDIR%\PlanningProduct.bat"

    :TWO
    call "%CURRDIR%\Organization.bat"

    :THREE
    call "%CURRDIR%\Measure.bat"

    pause
```

I did the following in the command line

```
I:\BatchMania>I:\BatchMania\Home.bat 1
```

and the output I get is funny as follows:

```
Planning
Organization
Measure
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This is weird. Hope to never write this kind of code!!!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the below produce what you expect?

```
:ONE
call "%CURRDIR%\PlanningProduct.bat"
GOTO OUT

:TWO
call "%CURRDIR%\Organization.bat"
GOTO OUT

:THREE
call "%CURRDIR%\Measure.bat"

:OUT
pause
```

Comment: Thanks Erik. That makes sens and it works. I thought labels would only work with goto.

Answer (score 4):

There are several items that need attention here:

- You have implemented "**fall-through**" scenarios, where THREE or TWO+THREE is executed in 2 distinct cases, or ONE+TWO+THREE in *all* other cases;
- I actually do not think the `if` statements work as intended: `[%1%]==[1]` should either be `[%1%]==[1%]` or `[%1]==[1]`;
- Should double backslashes be a problem when this script is run from the root, then consider using `%__CD__%`;
- All `if` statements can be omitted if you just use `goto batch%~1` (or similar) and rename your labels; OR
- All number labels can be omitted if you just specify the batch to call in the `if` statements and/or use `if-else` constructs.

Here are some alternative implementations:

```
@ECHO OFF
set CURRDIR=%CD%
goto :BATCH%~1 2>NUL
goto :UHOH

:BATCH1
call "%CURRDIR%\PlanningProduct.bat"
goto :DONE

:BATCH2
call "%CURRDIR%\Organization.bat"
goto :DONE

:BATCH3
call "%CURRDIR%\Measure.bat"
goto :DONE

:UHOH
echo Invalid parameter "%~1"

:DONE
pause
```

---

```
@ECHO OFF
set CURRDIR=%CD%

if "%~1"=="1" (
    call "%CURRDIR%\PlanningProduct.bat"
) else if "%~1"=="2" (
    call "%CURRDIR%\Organization.bat"
) else if "%~1"=="3" (
    call "%CURRDIR%\Measure.bat"
) else (
    echo Invalid parameter "%~1"
)
pause
```

---

```
@ECHO OFF
set CURRDIR=%CD%

set BAT=
if "%~1"=="1" set BAT=PlanningProduct.bat
if "%~1"=="2" set BAT=Organization.bat
if "%~1"=="3" set BAT=Measure.bat
call "%CURRDIR%\%BAT%" 2>NUL
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

After it junps to ONE and executes the call, it is just going to continue on the next line (TWO). A label does not change the execution sequence, it is still going to parse the file line by line unless you jump somewhere.

Either jump away to a specific point:

```
...
:ONE
call "%CURRDIR%\PlanningProduct.bat"
GOTO DONE

:TWO
...

:DONE
pause
```

or end the batch:

```
:ONE
call "%CURRDIR%\PlanningProduct.bat"
pause
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Thanks Anders. I thought labels would only work with goto. It works now